# Weighted Standard Deviation in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, standard-deviation

Im trying to write a weighted Standard Deviation function in VBA. 2 ranged inputs are supposed to output a value. However, it returns a #value error.

Edit: added worksheet.function

```
Public Function StDevWeighted(data As Range, weight As Range) As Double

    'https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/how-do-i-calculate-a-weighted-standard-deviation-in-excel
    
    Dim mean, top, bottom
    
    mean = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(data, weight) / WorksheetFunction.Length(data)
    
    top = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(weight, (data - mean) ^ 2)
    bottom = ((WorksheetFunction.Length(data) - 1) / WorksheetFunction.Length(data)) * WorksheetFunction.Sum(weight)
    
    StDevWeighted = WorksheetFunction.SQRT(top / bottom)
End Function
```

Comment: First, you need `WorksheetFunction.` or `Application.` before `SumProduct` and `Sum`... then what is `Length`?

Comment: You can't use `(data - mean)` if `data` is a multi-cell range.

Comment: In order to be able to debug your code you cannot use this function as a formula in a sheet (formulas cannot be debugged in VBA). To be able to debug it you need to call this function from a test procedure. I suggest to write a `Sub Test()` where you call `StDevWeighted` and give the same ranges as parameter as you did in the formula. Then include this test sub into the question above so we get a [mcve] for reproducing what you are doing.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, how do I fix this?

Comment: Would help to know which line was causing the function to drop out. Set a breakpoint on the first line, and use F8 to step through.

Comment: I would think you would use `data.Count` instead of `Length(data)`.

Comment: There's no `WorksheetFunction.Length`, nor is there `WorksheetFunction.SQRT`. Please follow @Peh's comment to debug further.

Comment: @Peh ... I seem to be able to happily set breakpoints and debug VBA UDF's when called from the spreadsheet, by setting a breakpoint. Anyhow, BigBen is right, you can't use (data-mean) in the SumProduct() call in VBA, even though you can in the spreadsheet itself: I imagine the routine which parses the formula in the spreadsheet tries to help out, whereas VBA doesnt. You can use the VBA in-built Sqr() function instead of SQRT().

Comment: @DS_London - yes, `data - mean` is a type mismatch because `data`, implicitly `data.Value`, is a 2D array.

Comment: @DS_London well, but it is a mess to do so. The only reliable way to debug a UDF is using a test procedure because it won't ever stop the code of an UDF and throw an error, instead it just returns `#Value` which tells you nothing. In order to get the error messages you need a test procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, unfortunately you have to do the work to calculate the square differences by yourself, item-by-item, and store the answers in a temporary array (see comments for why). I haven't checked the maths ... above my pay-grade!

```
Public Function StDevWeighted(rngData As Range, rngWeight As Range) As Double
    Dim dMean As Double
    Dim dTop As Double
    Dim dBottom As Double

    Dim vData As Variant
    vData = rngData
   
    dMean = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(rngData, rngWeight) / rngData.Count

    Dim vSqDiff() As Variant
    ReDim vSqDiff(1 To UBound(vData, 1), 1 To UBound(vData, 2))

    For r = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
            vSqDiff(r, c) = (vData(r, c) - dMean) ^ 2
        Next c
    Next r

    dTop = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(rngWeight, vSqDiff)
    dBottom = ((rngData.Count - 1) / rngData.Count) * WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngWeight)

    StDevWeighted = Sqr(dTop / dBottom)
End Function
```

PS. I tested this from my spreadsheet directly using the Debugger.

Comment: `Dim r As Long, c As Long` • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: For example if `dBottom` resolves as `0` because there are no values in `rngWeight` and the sum is `0`, then you will get an error because you devide by `0` in `dTop / dBottom` and you debug this directly as UDF (using as formula), you only see `#Value` and that there went something wrong. If you use a procedure you will get the information about **what** went wrong, you get a more detailed error message! That is why UDF debugging is not very useful.

Comment: @peh I do take your point ... but by setting a breakpoint at the start of the function, that breakpoint would get hit (unless you weren't satisfying the function's parameter types). Step through, and you would see that things go wrong on a particular line. You'd also pick up compiler errors, like that the Length() function doesn't exist. Run the function again, and this time inspect the input variables in the watch window before you step over the bug. To me that's quicker than writing a test sub-routine (and setting up all the data arrays) ... a sub-routine that you may also have to debug!

Comment: OK let us assume your function woud throws an exeption, but all you see is `#value` (because UDFs don't show error messages). You put a break point and "debug" your function. At the line where the error occurs the code execution immediately stops and outputs `#value` even if you step through by F8. Now you know in which line an error occurs but you still have no idea **which** error occurs because even with F8 no message is shown! So now you can either guess what the error actually is or you need to write a test procedure to be able to read the error message and fix this error.

Comment: Espeacially for not that experienced programmers (or if a more complex code line was used) the error message would help a lot to fix the error properly. And writing a test procedure is usually a one liner and almost no effort. Actually "test driven development" is a good practice (and worth the effort), check [How to unit test VBA code?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/19/how-to-unit-test-vba-code/) for more about this topic.